# Can I adjust the size of different label regions when using ggh4x package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I use ggplot2 and ggh4x to create some plots and there are some label rectangle regions.

Now I wanna adjust the rectangle size because the label front is not big enough so I want if I can make the bottom label rectangle smaller (just the bottom label rectangles). **I mean less heigher.**

Here is my reproducible code and code:

```
data<-structure(list(Name = structure(53:68, .Label = c("1_control", 
                                                        "1_CCM(Kit1 ko)", "2_control", "2_CCM(Pdcd20 ko)", "3_control", 
                                                        "3_1 day", "3_3 days", "3_1 month", "4_control", "4_1 day", "4_3 days", 
                                                        "4_1 month", "5_control", "5_1 day", "5_3 days", "5_1 month", 
                                                        "6_control", "6_TBI(1 day)", "7_control", "7_TBI(3 day)", "8_control", 
                                                        "8_TBI(1 month)", "9_control", "9_VEGF", "10_control", "10_VEGF", 
                                                        "11_Brain Healty", "12_control_1", "12_control_2", "12_AOD(Jnk1/2/3 ko)", 
                                                        "13_control", "13_Cpt1_ko(Cdh5 driven)", "14_control", "14_Tsc2ko(Tbx4 driven)", 
                                                        "15_control", "15_Zmpste24 ko", "16_control", "16_Adrenomedullin\nko(Cdh5 driven)", 
                                                        "17_Lung Healthy", "18_control(14w)", "18_carboplatin(14w)", 
                                                        "18_radiation(14w)", "18_6 weeks", "18_70 weeks", "19_ECs(bone marrow)", 
                                                        "20_control", "20_diabetic nephropathy", "21_control", "21_Alport syndrome", 
                                                        "22_control", "22_Alport syndrome", "23_Kidney Healthy", "24_control", 
                                                        "24_Differentiated", "25_Heart Healthy", "26_control", "26_Tumor", 
                                                        "27_control", "27_Nonalcoholic\nsteatohepatitis", "28_Liver Healthy", 
                                                        "29_control", "29_autoimmune uveitis", "30_control", "30_facioscapulohumeral\nmuscular dystrophy", 
                                                        "31_control", "31_RANKL ko", "32_control", "32_Notch1  +/vg", 
                                                        "32_Notch1  +/12", "32_Notch1  +/-", "32_Notch1  -/12"), class = "factor"), 
                     Disease = structure(c(24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
                                           28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("CCM\nmodel1", 
                                                                                                    "CCM\nmodel2", "Epilepsy", "EAE", "Stroke", "TBI\n1day", 
                                                                                                    "TBI\n3day", "TBI\n1month", "VEGF\nsti_DG\nregion", "VEGF\nsti_CA1\nregion", 
                                                                                                    "Healthy\n(Brain)", "AOD", "CPT1\nko", "Tsc2\nko", "Zmpste\n_24 ko", 
                                                                                                    "AM\nko", "Healthy\n(Lung)", "Chemo\nRadio\n(Tibiae)", "ECs\n(BM)", 
                                                                                                    "diabetic\nnephro\n_pathy", "Alport\nsyndrome\nEC\npopulation1", 
                                                                                                    "Alport\nsyndrome\nEC\npopulation2", "Healthy\n(Kidney)", 
                                                                                                    "Aorta", "Healthy\n(Heart)", "Tumor", "NASH", "Healthy\n(Liver)", 
                                                                                                    "EAU", "FSHD", "RANKL\nko", "Notch1\nmodified"), class = "factor"), 
                     Organ = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
                                         8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Brain", "Lung", "Bone", 
                                                                               "Kidney", "Aorta", "Liver", "Retina", "Mus", "Lymp", "Embryo"
                                         ), class = "factor"), fill = c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFF33", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#FFFFFF", "#00F5FF", "#FFFFFF", "#00F5FF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#666666", "#FFFFFF", "#7FC97F", "#FFFFFF", "#BEAED4", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                        "#A6D854"), Condition = c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", 
                                                                                                  "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", 
                                                                                                  "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#CCCCFF", "#fbb03b", "#fbb03b", "#fbb03b", 
                                                                                                  "#fbb03b"), Organ_fill = c("#FFFF33", "#FFFF33", "#FFFF33", 
                                                                                                                             "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#00F5FF", "#666666", 
                                                                                                                             "#666666", "#7FC97F", "#7FC97F", "#BEAED4", "#BEAED4", "#A6D854", 
                                                                                                                             "#A6D854"), mean = c(858.98750157615, 420.38122185754, 262.590442373838, 
                                                                                                                                                  185.670810881339, 233.452076898716, 3219.28563479013, 2427.32556269574, 
                                                                                                                                                  1552.81582140235, 394.765393523994, 420.454351698853, 1295.47692129111, 
                                                                                                                                                  1357.53823242958, 1352.71703262044, 1319.89488759262, 4.78327819764262, 
                                                                                                                                                  6.86013366170554), sd = c(55.535911372066, 15.5347305073907, 
                                                                                                                                                                            29.5537795773611, 17.4390137323828, 36.0381883614951, 641.298872189499, 
                                                                                                                                                                            338.296364941458, 254.748027714364, 17.1375059099585, 100.491982520438, 
                                                                                                                                                                            49.0693043847785, 191.034062908029, 105.031407429784, 185.916546617784, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1.21846060820158, 3.38993644072368)), row.names = 53:68, class = "data.frame")


#  2021-04-17 18:09:40

ggplot(data = data, aes(Name,mean, label = Name,fill=Organ)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge2", stat="identity",width = 0.85,color="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),position = position_dodge(0.85), width = .2) +
  facet_nested(.~Organ+Disease, scales="free",switch = "x",nest_line = TRUE)+
  ###  facet_wrap(strip.position="bottom")+
  theme_classic2() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.margin = unit(c(5, 10, 10, 10), "mm"),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"),
    ##        ggh4x.facet.nestline = element_line(colour = "blue"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle=0),
    strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

I mean if the rectangle can be smaller but don't change the label front size.
**I mean less heigher.**

Comment: just to clarify - what do you mean with "smaller"? Less wide,  Less high, or both?

Comment: @tjebo  Sorry, I want  less higher than before.

Comment: Any body here？？

Comment: @teunbrand Plz.

Comment: I don't know a solution for this problem on top of my head.  There isn't anything in the theme that discriminates lower from upper strips, neither in ggplot2 nor ggh4x. If you want to decrease the size of both boxes, you can set the margins `theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(...)))`. Otherwise you'd have to go into the gtable again, but this is always a very fragile solution to such problems.

Comment: @teunbrand
Yeah, I know. But I just wanna change the size of bottom label cells.
And I tried theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(...))) but it isnt suitable for my question. 

Could you show me how to use ggplotGrob to solve my problem just like changing the cell color last time ? Or still a loop?   There are little information about how to use ggplotGrob.

Comment: @teunbrand Sorry,sir. I think I still need your help. 

I really wanna change the height of the last label cells. Or all of the label cells.

I'm new to gtable and now I'm learning this package but it confused me if there is related parameter that can change the height of label cell.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks sir. I tried theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(...))) again and it works but a little. I know the size is besed on the font size and counts. If I set  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(b = 1))) or smaller "b" it will not work. Because in my real data the second bottom label cells contains more words though I know the label cells size are changed togather of the two rows. And I get a another idear that if I can make the bar wider so the label cells will be wider  ？

Comment: @teunbrand  I have a small question if I can change the label size  of  the last bottom labels ? I think this can do instead of changing the rectangle size.

Comment: So the `margin(b = ...)` doesn't change the margin of the bottom label, it changes the bottom margin of the text. If you want to set the vertical margins you need to change `b` and `t`. The strips themselves are as wide as the panels and get clipped if the panels become to small. I wouldn't know how a gtable approach would go, I haven't done this before.

Comment: @teunbrand Hah, vary thankful.  I tried to do this using the assign strip function you told me before but I get nothing.  

Sir, could you tell me how to change the bottom label font size ? I can make the bottom label wards size bigger.   I know there is a function strip.text.x = element_text(size = , angle=) can make all the label size smaller or bigger togather .  Could I change only the bottom label size  ??

Comment: You could possibly do this with the [ggtext](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/) package, but you'd have to pre-format your text with markdown/html tags.